# WP_Query meta value order is not working

Tags: wp-query

I am fetching results based on numeric value of post metadata. But I am getting 2 types of results based on whether I'm using `2` or `02` .

Take a look at the images

[image]

Here is another

[image]

When I am using `02` its okay. But when I am using only `2` its not okay.
I am organizing post ids based on `meta_value`.

Here is the result when I'm using `2`

```
3866
3864
3865
3861
3862
```

Here is the result when I'm using `02`

```
3866
3864
3861
3862
3865
```

Why this is not working?

I am using `$args['orderby']  = 'meta_value meta_value_num';`

Comment: What if you only sort by `meta_value_num`?

Answer (score 1):

If the variable you are storing in `meta_value` were an integer, you would not be able to store it as '02'. So, apparently, your are storing a string. This indeed gives different orders depending on whether you store '02' or '2', as is described under `meta_value` in the [codex on `WP_Query`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters).

So, as the codex says, you must force the string to be converted to integers by ordering with `meta_value_num` or by additionally specifying `meta_type=NUMERIC`.